# How to put boolean on button click?

Tags: android, button, boolean

I have this countdown timer that run when button is clicked below are the code.

```
static public void starttimer() {
    t1 = date3 - date;
    progressbarstatus ();
    starttimercd ();

    timer = new CountDownTimer ( totalSeconds, 1000 ) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            if (isclicked = true) {
                secondc = totalSeconds - millisUntilFinished;
                mEndtime = System.currentTimeMillis () + secondc;
                countdowntext ();
            }
            if (isclicked = false) {
                secondc = System.currentTimeMillis () - mEndtime;
                countdowntext ();
                timer.cancel ();

            }

            percentage = Math.round ( secondc / t1 * 100 );
            tvp.setText ( percentage + "%" );
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timerrunning = false;
        }
    }.start ();
}
```

i have tried to put boolean on the on the listener.

```
    btn_start.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isclicked = true;
            starttimer ();
        }

    });
```

the problem is when i run the app the timer is running by default. Does anyone have any solution on how to make the timer runs only when the button is clicked and how to put boolean on onclicklisterner? Appreciated  if anyone could help.

Comment: Make the boolean false in oncreate, then make it true after clicking

Comment: have done that but still the timer running. is there is any solution other than boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put boolean in **onclick** function. Put if out of **starttimer**. When the boolean is true function will run regardless of boolean to be *true* or *false* after that.

Comment: Have tried that..it works bro thanks for the solution..i guess i should not put boolean on onclick function..thanks again bro..